# Chrome API IME not working

Tags: json, api, google-chrome, ime

I've been trying to run google's sample IME, without success. The problem is, it's not even executing. As you can see in the code below, console.log should give me at least one line of feedback, and is not:

```
var context_id = -1;
// Copyright 2013 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

var ime_api = chrome.input.ime;

var context_id = -1;

console.log("Initializing IME");  //THIS LINE I EXPECT TO SEE, NO MATTER WHAT
```

These are the files I'm using, if you wanna read them:
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/input.ime/basic/main.js
http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/input.ime/basic/manifest.json

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

What's your OS?  If you're on Chrome OS, [there are 3 steps](https://github.com/google/extra-keyboards-for-chrome-os) to enabling an IME:

1. load unpacked extension
2. logout/login
3. `ctrl`+`shift` to switch input methods

I imagine for other operating systems, there is some similar "restart chrome" type of sequence required.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to be running chrome os.

Second, make sure you set your language to english (united states) and select the input method "Test IME". After that restart your chromebook (or whatever computer).